# Can't get contacts using Intent.ACTION_PICK

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

I am trying to get a contact from contact-list but for some reason I can't get it. I have folowed some guides. This is my code:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.menu_ice_add:
          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
          startActivityForResult(intent, RequestCodes.PICK_CONTACT);
          return true;          
      default:
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
}
```

When I debug, It always goes to default case, it returns super.onOptionItemSelected(item);

```
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    // se comprueba de qué activity está volviendo
    switch(requestCode) {       
    case (RequestCodes.PICK_CONTACT) :
          if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
              Uri contactData = data.getData();

              ContactUtils.addContactInfo(getActivity(), contactData, adapter);

          }             
          break;
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

It never starts onActivityResult.

Can anybody give me a hint? I would appreciate it a lot. Thank you.

**EDIT 1**

I must say that this code works on Android 2.3, but it doesn't work on KitKat (those are the devices I have)

**EDIT 2**

I have added android.permission.READ_CONTACTS in menifest

**EDIT 3 (SOLVED)**

The problems was not the Intent. I am using Fragments and I was calling onActivityResult, but I didn't know **I had to do "super.onActivityResult(arg0,arg1,arg2)" on the activity where my Fragment is attached**.

I will not delete the question because maybe this could be helpful.

Thanxs anyway to everybody.

Comment: Have u add permission android.permission.READ_CONTACTS in menifest?

Comment: Yes, I have add respective permissions

Comment: If its always going to default case then there might be problem in inflating menu or selecting the proper id's. Check that once

Answer (score 0):

> When I debug, It always goes to default case, it returns super.onOptionItemSelected(item);

Then you have the wrong item ID in your `case` statement, or your `R` class is out of sync with your resources (clean your project, such as Project > Clean in Eclipse, to clear up that problem).

> It never starts onActivityResult.

That is because you are not calling `startActivityForResult()`, due to the problem with your menu resources and `onOptionsItemSelected()` implementation, noted above.

Also note that you do not need `READ_CONTACTS` for the uses shown in your code, though you may need it for whatever is in `ContactUtils.addContactInfo()`.

FWIW, [this directory](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ConfigChange) contains five sample projects, all of which successfully use `ACTION_PICK` for `ContactsContracts.Contacts.CONTENT_URI`. The differences between the projects come down to how they handle configuration changes (e.g., screen rotation).